# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddAWSService' and no accessible extension method 'AddAWSService' error in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-sqs

I am setting up `Aws SQS` in `asp.net core 2.22` project. I am adding aws configuration lines in my `Program.cs` file. Here is my `Program.cs` file.

```js
using Amazon.SQS;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace analytics
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set;}

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options =>
                {
                    options.AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
            });


             // AWS Configuration
                    var awsoptions = Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
                    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsoptions);
                    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>();

                    // Worker Service
                    // services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseCors(options =>
            {
                options.AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So i am receiving these errors on console

```
Startup.cs(40,52): error CS1061: 'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'GetAWSOptions' 
and no accessible extension method 'GetAWSOptions' accepting a first argument of type 
'IConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
[D:\OfficeProjects\beelinksanalytics\analytics.csproj]

Startup.cs(41,30): error CS1061: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 
'AddDefaultAWSOptions' and no accessible extension method 'AddDefaultAWSOptions' accepting a first 
argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?) [D:\OfficeProjects\beelinksanalytics\analytics.csproj]

Startup.cs(42,30): error CS1061: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 
'AddAWSService' and no accessible extension method 'AddAWSService' accepting a first argument of 
type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
reference?) [D:\OfficeProjects\beelinksanalytics\analytics.csproj]
```

Basically i want to implement `Aws SQS` service to listen queue messages and want to perform some actions based on those messages. So i am struggling to configure `Aws Sdk` and `aws sqs` in `asp.net core 2.2` project

I didn't find any relevant documentation of how to configure `aws sqs` in asp.net core 2.2. Please tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: `GetAWSOptions` is part of the [AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/) package. You need to add this package and add the `Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup` namespace reference


This is described in [Configuring the AWS SDK for .NET with .NET Core](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html).

Comment: Add the package and namespace reference the same way you added Amazon.SQS and the `using Amazon.SQS;` reference

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. If you will post this as answer so i will accept that.

Answer (score 10):

just run this in your command line as mentioned [@panagiotis-kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) (select version that you want [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/))

> dotnet add package AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup --version 3.3.101

verify that the reference was added in your .csproj

[image]

this worked for me, I hope as well for you